# consolidate repetitive if-functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

What's the right way to consolidate this into one `if` statement?

```
$('span').filter(function() {

    var myEl = $(this);
    var myText = myEl.text();

        if (myText.match('foo')) {
            $(myEl).addClass('foo');
        }

        if (myText.match('bar')) {
            $(myEl).addClass('bar');
        }

        if (myText.match('baz')) {
            $(myEl).addClass('baz');
        }

  });
```

Comment: why is this all stuff in a `.filter()`?

Comment: Turn it into a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this for example :

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].forEach(function(v){
   if (myText.match(v)) myEl.addClass(v);
});
```

or, if you want to be compatible with IE8 (which hasn't [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) :

```
$.each(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], function(_, v){
   if (myText.match(v)) myEl.addClass(v);
});
```

Note that I replaced `$(myEl)` with `myEl` as `myEl` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: +1. I was writing the code using `$(['foo','bar','baz']).each(function(){})` and I knew there was a better way :D looks great

Comment: @Ejay In fact using `$.each` (and not `.each`) lets you avoid importing a shim while being compatible with IE8.

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice :) . `$.each(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']), function(_, v){` I think you've an extra `)` there

Answer (score 3):

An option with regular expressions:

```
 var matches = myText.match(/foo|var|baz/g);
 if(matches) myEl.addClass(matches.join(" "));
```